# What is the functionality of "non_missing_aes" in ggproto of ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, ggproto

I'm writing extensions for `ggplot2`, and found that there's a newly added `non_missing_aes` parameter in `ggproto` that has not been explained in the official documentations of `ggplot2` and official guide of extending `ggplot2`, could anyone tell me its functionality, and the difference between `required_aes`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TLDR

`require_aes` specifies the aesthetic mappings that must be exist **before** everything in a `geom_*()` or `stat_*()` is passed into a ggproto object, while `non_missing_aes` specifies the aesthetic mappings that must exist **after** the necessary processing steps by different functions defined in the said ggproto object.

## Longer explanation

Since you are writing extensions, I assume you are familiar with how a data frame is passed into `ggplot()` and inherited by each relevant layer (or passed directly into each layer), then passed into the relevant Geom / Stat ggproto objects and transformed along the way.

`non_missing_aes`, along with `required_aes`, is referenced as part of this data transformation process, in `Geom$handle_na` as well as `Stat$compute_layer` functions, from which all other Geoms & Stats inherit by default.

More specifically, `non_missing_aes` is found within the `remove_missing` function as follows (I added the function argument names below for clarity):

```
remove_missing(df = data, 
               na.rm = params$na.rm, 
               vars = c(self$required_aes, self$non_missing_aes), 
               name = snake_class(self))
```

From `?remove_missing`, we can tell that this is where all columns listed in either `require_aes` or `non_missing_aes` are checked, and rows with missing values in any of the checked columns are dropped from the data frame.

But why use `non_missing_aes`? Why not specify all such columns in `require_aes`? A look at some Geoms / Stats that actually specify something in `non_missing_aes` suggests why:

[GeomBar](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/geom-bar.r) (comments below are from the actual code found on GitHub):

```
required_aes = c("x", "y"),

# These aes columns are created by setup_data(). They need to be listed here so
# that GeomRect$handle_na() properly removes any bars that fall outside the defined
# limits, not just those for which x and y are outside the limits
non_missing_aes = c("xmin", "xmax", "ymin", "ymax"),
...
```

[GeomRaster](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/8724c8e3569b5d887d9e24c9fa3daf55a50cdcb7/R/geom-raster.r):

```
required_aes = c("x", "y"),
non_missing_aes = "fill",
default_aes = aes(fill = "grey20", alpha = NA),
...
```

[GeomSegment](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/c84d9a075280d374892e5a3e0e25dd0ba246caad/R/geom-segment.r):

```
required_aes = c("x", "y", "xend", "yend"),
non_missing_aes = c("linetype", "size", "shape"),
default_aes = aes(colour = "black", size = 0.5, linetype = 1, alpha = NA),
...
```

[GeomPoint](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/344bfea39aaadbb90c455570f7fdf30d33a1a4fd/R/geom-point.r):

```
required_aes = c("x", "y"),
non_missing_aes = c("size", "shape", "colour"),
default_aes = aes(shape = 19, colour = "black", size = 1.5, fill = NA,
                  alpha = NA, stroke = 0.5),
...
```

[StatYdensity](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/669a606308d1b28774bc321c0c60db926fcb1e25/R/stat-ydensity.r) (note that this Stat is usually used with `geom_violin`, which specifies `weight = 1` in its `default_aes`):

```
required_aes = c("x", "y"),
non_missing_aes = "weight",
...
```

In each case, the aesthetic mappings listed in `non_missing_aes` are ones that are **NOT** necessarily specified by the user at the point a ggplot object is generated, so the corresponding columns may not exist in the data frame from the onset.

For GeomBar, xmin / xmax / ymin / ymax columns are only calculated **from** the given data frame during `GeomBar$setup_data()`. For the rest, the `non_missing_aes` mappings are included in their respective Geoms' `default_aes`, so while they *could* exist from the onset if the user included something like `colour = <some variable in the data>` in `geom_*()`, the columns will be created at a later stage otherwise, and filled with default values.

In either case, by the time the data frame is evaluated by the `remove_missing` function, all columns in either `required_aes` or `non_missing_aes` should be present, but since not all were inputted by the user from the onset, we can't specify all of them in `required_aes`, because any aesthetic mapping listed in `required_aes` but not present in the `geom_*()` / `stat_*()` would trigger an error:

> Error: geom_* requires the following missing aesthetics: some_aes_or_other

Comment: A bit off topic, but due to your great answer you might also know which arguments need to be specified w/i `extra_params`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69766977/6583972