# Which arguments need to be specified w/i `extra_params` for a new `ggproto`

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

Out of curiosity, is there any documentation on which parameters need to be defined inside `extra_params` for a `ggplot2::ggproto` object?

My initial thought was that it could be the parameters defined within the argument `params` of a `ggplot2::layer()`, but this is not true.

If you look at the `extra_params` of the [`GeomRibbon`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/759c63c2fd9e00ba3322c1b74b227f63c98d2e06/R/geom-ribbon.r#L86), for example, I would guess that only the parameters that are not explicitly included in the respective `draw_group()` function call must be included. For the `GeomRibbon` example:

- `extra_params` includes `"orientation"`, which is probably addressed by `params$extra_params` w/i `setup_data()`,
- whereas `extra_params` does not include`"outline.type"`, which is directly handed over to the function call `draw_group()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the finer details of ggplot2 extension documentation are just comments in the source code, or the source code itself. For the [`extra_params`](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/5141ef58442114a40c733a0ab387710c8f9cc1ec/R/geom-.r#L165-L170) field, it reads:

```r
  # Most parameters for the geom are taken automatically from draw_panel() or
  # draw_groups(). However, some additional parameters may be needed
  # for setup_data() or handle_na(). These can not be imputed automatically,
  # so the slightly hacky "extra_params" field is used instead. By
  # default it contains `na.rm`
```

So indeed, most extra parameters are implied by the formals of the `draw_panel` and `draw_group` methods of ggproto classes.

The only place where it is used is the `parameters()` method of `Geom` and `Stat` classes.

This `parameters()` method itself is used in 3 places:

1. The `Geom$draw_layer()` method, where it is used to determine the parameters to pass on to the `draw_panel()` method.
2. The `Stat$compute_layer()` method, where it serves the same purpose.
3. The `layer()` function to check if the input are valid parameters.

So to answer your question, you should put any parameters there that aren't used in any of the `draw_{panel/group}` or `compute_{panel/group}` methods, but don't want `layer()` to give a warning about.